# Select and install software / Installation step failed

Tags: 14.04, networking, system-installation, pxe

I am trying network install from PXE with the following image:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/

I have copied this entire directory into `TFTP` server root and my computer was booted and passed almost well until this step. Then it gave this error `Select and install software` / `Installation step failed`.

No any error messages / codes provided.

How to know what is happening?

**UPDATE**

Some extra details which may help to guess the problem. This computer has two hard drives. Old harddrive has Windows 8.1 installed on it. It is 500Gb in size. Second hard drive is empty, is of size 1500Gb and I was intended to install Ubuntu on it. This drive was detected as `sda` and I selected automatic partitioning for it. Remained drive has ntfs and I was thinking don't care of it.

**UPDATE 2**

I was able to save logs to mounted filesystem to `/root` directory and then was able to go to the shell.

In the shell I found, that Internet access is OK and that the mirror site is pingable.

Also I found it created some files in `/root/install`. These files are `hardware-summary`, `lsb-release`, `status`, `install-report.template`, `partman` and `syslog`. Neither contains any apparent (for me) messages concerning the process of installation and it's failed step.

Comment: Could you add more details about your setting while installation? Like which mirror did you choose, NIC setup...

Comment: I tried two mirrors, `us` and `russia`, on `NIC` setup I have selected `eth0`, and it automatically set up by `DHCP`, said "success". The problem is that I have no details. May be I can reach some logs somewhere?

Comment: could you get picture of the last screen with that error? If you still have "Go Back" press it many time till you reach the "Ubuntu Installer main menu", there you can choose to save debug log or the drop to shell, if you are not familiar with `busybox`, run `ip link`,  `ip address`, `ip route` to get current nic setup. you can use `ping` to test mirror connection. to see all commands available run `help`, `ls /sbin /bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin`

Comment: Could you post `hardware-summary`, `status`, `partman` & `syslog` . When you get back to the installer menu, In which step you found the highlight?